# What is docs package and how to use it?

Tags: package-management, documentation

There are some docs package in repository like:

```
glib2-docs
linux-docs
php-docs
python-docs
```

What I can undestand form its name (docs) is it kind like documentation or something for the package. And then, I try `man linux`. It gives me `No manual entry for linux`. So, what is that `docs` package? If it's a documentation, how can I open it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs packages contains the documentation set for the related package.  These should be installed in `/usr/share/doc/` directory tree.  You can browse this directory for the installed documentation packages.

If you have the apache web server package installed, you can browse `http://localhost/doc` to view the documentation.  This is normally restricted to the access only from the same host, buy you can adjust the access restrictions to make it more widely accessible.  I normally make it available on the local area network, but not the Internet.